# as vs. such as vs. for instance

Tags: meaning, as

Can one say

> 1a. When you push someone else to commit a crime, as by persuasion or threats, you are partly responsible for what he has done.
>
> 1b. When you push someone else to commit a crime, such as by persuasion or threats, you are partly responsible for what he has done.
>
> 1c. When you push someone else to commit a crime, for instance by persuasion or threats, you are partly responsible for what he has done.

===============================================

> 2a. When anyone damages someone else's property, as by water or by fire, they will have to pay for the reparations.
>
> 2b. When anyone damages someone else's property, such as by water or by fire, they will have to pay for the reparations.
>
> 2c. When anyone damages someone else's property, for instance by water or by fire, they will have to pay for the reparations.

The first three are supposed to have the same meaning and the second three are supposed to have the same meaning.

Comment: The first group of three sentences have the same meaning, as do the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples

> **such as**
>   *such as* by water or by fire
>
> **for instance**
>   *for instance* by water or by fire

and by extension

> **for example**
>   *for example* by water or by fire

may all be used interchangeably.

However using a *bare*

> **as**
>   *as* by water or by fire

might possibly be better expressed as

> **as might be**
>   *as might be* by water or by fire
>
> **as may be**
>   *as may be* by water or by fire

to have the same interchangeability.